# sitecore FXM publishes content in all pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-fxm

Using Sitecore 8.2

There is an external non-sitecore site with 2 pages - 'Register' & 'Thankyou'. User will click on Submit in the 'Register' page, and on successful submission, the 'Thankyou' page will load, which means, in the site navigation menu, 'Thankyou' is not available.

The requirement is as follows :

Verify the user and check if he/she has already visited the 'Thankyou' (meaning, user has submitted the form). If yes, then show some personalized content in the 'Register' page on page load, using Sitecore.

I have placed the beacon script in both the 'Register' & 'Thankyou' pages. For a test, created a simple html rendering and applied it to the 'Register' page via the experience editor.

After publish, I see that the Sitecore content shows up in both the 'Register' & 'Thankyou' live pages. Why is this happening. How to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FXM uses something called page filters to restrict where content exists. In order to pinpoint which page on your external site shows which piece of content you need to set these up e.g.:

`FXM Site
/Matcher Rule
/Matcher Rule/Content`

The rule can contain things like 'if the url matches ###' then success (or failure).

If you need more information have a look at http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/sitecore-fxm-page-filters-matcher-rules/ as it details this feature.